# How to count number of sessions by android device in Data Studio?

Tags: session, sum, looker-studio

How to count number of sessions by android device in Data Studio? When I used it's function in data studio:

```
SUM(
CASE 
    WHEN  REGEXP_CONTAINS(mobile device, '.*Apple.*') THEN sessions
 
    ELSE NULL
END)
```

But have an error: `you can't use aggregates`.

What will the correct function look like to get the result I need?

Comment: Could you elaborate by providing a publicly editable Google Data Studio Report (additionally, a Google Sheet if it's the data set) of the scenario (using sample data that shows 1) Input values (~10 rows) 2) Expected output 3) An attempt at solving the issue)? It would help users visualise the issue and test out suggestions on a specific use case with objective right / wrong answers. Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it would be difficult to pinpoint a suggestion and the issue, e.g. Data Set, Data Source, Report, Fields, Chart

Answer (score 0):

To simplify, let's first try to count the number of Apple devices vs. non-Apple devices.

**tl;dr** create a calculated field which equates to `Apple` when `Mobile Device Info` contains `Apple`. Otherwise, it equates to `Android`. See a [working example here](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7979350e-e3c1-43f7-9b0e-6a72b6498892).

**Steps**

1. You need to create a calculated field which acts as a dummy dimension.

Field name:
`* Mobile Device Platform`
(it's helpful to put an asterisk before calculated fields to find them easier in the list)

Formula:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Mobile Device Info,'Apple') THEN 'Apple'
  ELSE 'Android'
END
```

2. Use the newly created dimension to split the sessions using a table that has `* Mobile Device Platform` as the only dimension and `Sessions` as a metric.
3. Add other conditions in the formula above to capture more nuances in the data. For example:

```
CASE
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Mobile Device Info,'Apple') THEN 'Apple'
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Mobile Device Info,'Huawei') THEN 'EMUI / HarmonyOS'
  WHEN REGEXP_CONTAINS(Mobile Device Info,'(not set)') THEN 'Unknown'
  ELSE 'Android'
END
```